# ¿Como puedo generar un numero que no sea el mismo despues de que hagan click en el boton imprimir con javascritp?

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios, eventos, clickonce

tenngo un formulario en HTML%, con algunas variables, cuando la persona complete todo y haga click en el boton imprimir además de imprimir tiene que generar, un nro, despues de eso se tiene que limpiar la pagina y seguir generando un nuevo nro. 
Dejo abajo mi codigo. Alguien me pede ayudar?

````
```        <div>
        <p class="parrafo">Usted sera llamado por el siguiente número</p>
        <output id="number" name="codigo"></output>             
    </div>
        <!-- <input class="boton" type="button" value="imprimir" id="imprimir" >    -->

    <button class="boton" type="button" id="botoncito" onclick="javascript:window.print()">Imprimir</button>        ```
````

````
if form = true {
    function numeroPorClick() {
        var num = (0 + "");
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById("botoncito") {
    document.addEventListener("click", botoncito)
}        ```
````

Comment: El código Javascript que has escrito no es válido. ¿Ese es tu código o lo copiaste mal al escribir la pregunta?

Comment: Hola! finalmente el formulario quedo así.... ese codigo lo escribi pero con pocos recursos. https://codepen.io/juliana-gonzalez-the-encoder/pen/rNORxgK